Most efficient way to fine tune SDXL for range of product
I want to fine tune SDXL using LoRA on a range of product so that SDXL can generate images of those product later on.
I have many products. What is the most efficient way to fine tune?
Do I just train a single LoRA for all the product or multiple ones for each product or any other alternative. The product include furniture, and other sellable items.

one option would be to fine tune using dreambooth, that way you can have each model generate images of one product. if you have images containing multiple products you could fine tune with that. another option is to look at something like ziplora https://github.com/mkshing/ziplora-pytorch/tree/main

you can also try to generate images using sdxl (any model that fits your needs) to generate the suroundings and then place the products with inpainting. or the other way around use outpainting on images with products
